# Angular2 applying Pipe after data is received

Tags: typescript, angular

I have an `Object` that is used to manage the data received from the back end. 
It is initiated with all the fields as `display: false`, and if I receive that specific field from the server, I will eventually change it to `true`.

**filterGroups (initial):**

```
export let filterGroups: any = {
    genericFilters: {
        iboId: {
            'display': false,
            'template': ''
        },
        iboCode: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'text/iboCode'
        },
        iboName: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'text_input_iboName'
        },
        iboSurname: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'text_input_iboSurname'
        },
        iboRank: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'select/multi_iboRank',
        },
        iboEmail: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'text_input_iboEmail'
        },
        iboNewsletter: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'select/simple_iboNewsletter',
        },
    },
    orderFilters: {
        iboTotalOrders: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'compound/iboTotalOrders',
        }
    },
    peFilters: {
        iboTotalPE: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'checkbox/iboTotalPE',
        }
    },
};
```

In my template, I want to have as many `div` as filter groups. In this case we have 3 filter groups: `genericFilters`, `orderFilters` and `peFilters`.

This `Object` will be modified as soon as I receive data from the server (which I call in my `constructor`).

And so, my `filterGroups` will look like this after I have received the data from my **async call**.

**filterGroups (after async call):**

```
export let filterGroups: any = {
    genericFilters: {
        iboId: {
            'display': true,
            'template': ''
        },
        iboCode: {
            'display': true,
            'template': 'text/iboCode'
        },
        iboName: {
            'display': true,
            'template': 'text_input_iboName'
        },
        iboSurname: {
            'display': true,
            'template': 'text_input_iboSurname'
        },
        iboRank: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'select/multi_iboRank',
        },
        iboEmail: {
            'display': true,
            'template': 'text_input_iboEmail'
        },
        iboNewsletter: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'select/simple_iboNewsletter',
        },
    },
    orderFilters: {
        iboTotalOrders: {
            'display': true,
            'template': 'compound/iboTotalOrders',
        }
    },
    peFilters: {
        iboTotalPE: {
            'display': false,
            'template': 'checkbox/iboTotalPE',
        }
    },
};
```

Now, in my template I have this:

**Template (HTML):**

```
<div *ngFor="let group of filterGroups | keysCheckDisplay">
    <div>
        <h4>{{group.key}}</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

And, obviusly, here is my `@Pipe`.

**@Pipe:**

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { isNullOrUndefined } from 'util';

@Pipe({name: 'keysCheckDisplay'})
export class KeysCheckDisplayPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, args: string[]): any {
        let keys = [];
        for (let key in value) {
            if (!isNullOrUndefined(value[key])) {
                let display = false;
                for (let keyChild in value[key]) {
                    if (!isNullOrUndefined(value[key][keyChild]) && value[key][keyChild]['display'] === true) {
                        display = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (display === true) {
                    keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
                }
            }
        }
        return keys;
    }
}
```

In this `@Pipe` as you can see I do several things:

- Loop through the `filterGroups` object
- Check for each group within the object if exists a child with `display: true`.

**The functionality:**

I want this `@Pipe` to loop through my `Object`and **return me the 'filter groups' that have at least 1 element with `display: true`**.

**The Issue:**

The `@Pipe` is getting the first version of the `filterGroups` object, and is ignoring the fact that the object changes as soon as I receive the data from the server.

The `@Pipe` works fine if I modify the initial values of the `filterGroups` object.

**What I have tried:**

- Research, research, research
- I changed the `@Pipe` to inpure, but I hate this solution because of awful performance and also it entered an infinite loop.
- I have also tried this approach: 
  `*ngFor="let group of filterGroups | async | keysCheckDisplay"`. 
  But it throwed the following error:

> Error: InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'

**Possible solutions?**

- Modify the `@Pipe`?
- Modify the initial `object`?
- Create a second `@Pipe` to loop through the first Pipe's result?

I hope it was detailed and clear, if not, please don't esitate to comment asking for more details and I will gladly update the post.

Thank you beforehand!

Comment: Do you have a Plunkr ? It would be great to help you out ! Using async pipe won't help you here as you're not working on an observable. Did you change the `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in your component ? (to OnPush maybe ?)

Comment: Hey @Maxime! No, I did not change `ChangeDetectionStrategy`. I will have a look at it and see how I could use it in this case. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pure pipe is only called when the data changes. This means when "data" is a new object instance. If only the content of the object is modified, then Angular change detection won't recognize it as change and won't call the pipe.

Possible approaches

- make the pipe impure: usually quite a burden for performance
- copy the object like:

```
var tmp = this.data; this.data = {}; Object.assign(this.data, tmp);
```

- add an additional parameter to the pipe and update the parameter value

```
*ngFor="let item of data | myPipe:counter"
```

```
// updated `data`
// this.counter++;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I will try this out, and let you know as soon as I finish implementing it!

Comment: I opted for the second approach. I just created a new object just for layout/render purposes. And left the original as it was because other features depend on it. Doing so, I keep all my functionality intact and the layout functionality (with my new object) works as I intended. Thank you. I have still a long way ahead of me in Angular 2 and 4. :D

Comment: Yup, quite a lot of stuff to learn. Glad to hear you could make it work.